# How to compare hours and minutes?

Tags: python

I have four variables:

```
start_hour = '12'
start_minute = '00'
end_hour = '22'
end_minute = '30'
```

and from datetime:

```
current_hour = datetime.now().hour
curren_minute = datetime.now().minute
```

And I want to compare if the current time is within the range:

```
if int(start_hour) <= current_hour and int(end_hour) >= current_hour:
    something
```

But how to implement this with minutes?

Comment: The same way you do it with hours?

Comment: how do you mean, you want something to happen from 12:30 to 22:30

Comment: Convert both times to minutes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A much better way to go about this would beto convert both times to minutes:

```
start_time = int(start_hour)*60 + int(start_minute)
end_time = int(end_hour)*60 + int(end_minute)
current_time =  datetime.now().hour*60 +datetime.now().minute
if start_time <= current_time and end_time >= current_time:
    #doSomething
```

If you need to include seconds, convert everything to seconds.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to do the comparisons reliably. You can specify a delta in different units of time (hours, minutes, seconds, etc.) Then you don't have to worry about converting to hours, minutes, etc. explicitly.

For example, to check if the current time is more than an hour from the  `start_time`:

```
if abs(datetime.now() - start_time) > datetime.timedelta(hours=1):
    # Do thing
```

You can also use `timedelta` to shift a time by a given amount:

```
six_point_five_hours_from_now = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=6, minutes=30)
```

The nice thing about `timedelta` apart from easy conversions between units is it will automatically handle time differences that span multiple days, etc.

Answer (score 9):

What about:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()

>>> breakfast_time = now.replace( hour=7, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0 )

>>> lunch_time = now.replace( hour=12, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0 )

>>> coffee_break = now.replace( hour=16, minute=00, second=0, microsecond=0 )

>>> breakfast_time <= lunch_time <= coffee_break
True
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple and clear way to do it all with just `datetime` objects is:

```
now = datetime.now()
start = now.replace(hour = int(start_hour), minute = int(start_minute))
end = now.replace(hour = int(end_hour), minute = int(end_minute))

if start <= now <= end:
    print('something')
```